# CNN Arrow image classifier on differently shaped arrows

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I've been using Keras with Tensorflow to classify a normalized 60x60 grayscale image of an arrow into 4 categories, its orient, up, down, left, right. I have created a dataset of about ~1800 images, almost equally distributed into said categories.

However, there's a problem with classification. From the source where I have created the dataset, there are two types of arrows, arrow shape 1,
[image]

and arrow shape 2.[image]

The accuracy is okay for arrows which are shaped like 1(about ~70% validation accuracy), but for arrows like number 2, terrible.

I've went through my dataset, and about 90% of the dataset images are arrow shape 1.

Does that mean that the lack of traning data for arrow shape 2 is the reason that it cannot classify them as well as shape 1, and therefore increasing the dataset for shape 2 resolve this issue?

If true, doesn't that mean that my model has failed to generalize?

Also, if the arrow colors are inverted, will the network be affected by this?

Here is the source I'm using to train data:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from random import shuffle
import glob


train_dir = "images\\cropped\\traindata"
test_dir = "images\\cropped\\testdata"
MODEL_NAME = "ARROWS.model"

img_size = 60


# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import adam
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras import backend as K

from tensorflow import Session, ConfigProto, GPUOptions
gpuoptions = GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
session = Session(config=ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpuoptions))
K.set_session(session)
classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(img_size, img_size, 1)))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation("relu"))

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3)))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation("relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))
#classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation("relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))
#classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))

classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(128))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation("relu"))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))


classifier.add(Dense(4))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation("softmax"))


classifier.compile(optimizer = adam(lr=1e-6), loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=12)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=12)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('images/cropped/traindata',
                                                 color_mode="grayscale",
                                                 target_size = (img_size, img_size),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical', shuffle=True)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('images/cropped/testdata',
                                            color_mode="grayscale",
                                            target_size = (img_size, img_size),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical', shuffle=True)

with open("class_indices.txt", "w") as indices_fine:  # Log debug data to file
    indices_fine.write(str(classifier.summary()))
    indices_fine.write("\n")
    indices_fine.write("training_set indices:\n"+str(training_set.class_indices))
    indices_fine.write("test_set indices:\n"+str(test_set.class_indices))


tbCallBack = TensorBoard(log_dir='./log', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,steps_per_epoch = 8000,epochs = 15,validation_data = test_set,validation_steps = 2000, shuffle=True, callbacks=[tbCallBack])

classifier.save("arrow_classifier_keras_gray.h5")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does that mean that the lack of traning data for arrow shape 2 is the
>   reason that it cannot classify them as well as shape 1, and therefore
>   increasing the dataset for shape 2 resolve this issue?

Your dataset distribution is very important and can cause bias toward a particular class and not performing as you expect. In your case, the number of cases of *shape 2* is much smaller than your *shape 1*, hence creating bias in your Deep Learning model to somehow assuming all of the down arrows must be like shape 1, and not shape 2. Solution? You already know the answer: **Increasing the dataset for shape 2** or **make shape 1 and shape 2 equally distributed in down arrow class**.

> If true, doesn't that mean that my model has failed to generalize?

Your dataset distribution of images caused the model to fail generalizing well on that particular class (down arrow). If your model works well on other classes, the problem is not your model, but your dataset for down arrow class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would also like to know if the training images' colors were inverted(some images in my dataset have inverted colors from the sample image), would that affect the traning result?

Comment: Yes indeed. They should be similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Just imagine your first image is a tiny cat and a second is a fat cat, like Garfield. The distribution of cats is something we cannot change, but we need to detect all the cats (even when the cats are inverted or sprayed in pink).

What I would do is for instance if I have 1000 of tiny cats, I may filter some of the images add some distortions, and effect to make the training set bigger. This is called data augmentation.

You don't need per purpose to make the number of fat cat images equal the number of tiny cats images if at the end you recognize them all well and you have trained your image classifier with let's say ~98% accuracy on this dataset.

It is important to test.

NOTE: CNN should be good at detecting images with inverted colors. It is because they use the convolution technique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I accepted the other answer since it was posted faster.

Comment: No worries, glad you liked the answer @Dashadower